# Docker not exposing ports as expected

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have the below dockerfile that I am trying to build. At the end of the file I am attempting to expose ports 8888 and 6006.

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.2-devel-ubuntu16.04
LABEL maintainer="nweir <nweir@iqt.org>"

ARG solaris_branch='master'


# prep apt-get and cudnn
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install requirements
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    bc \
    bzip2 \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    libgdal-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libncurses-dev \
    libgl1 \
    jq \
    nfs-common \
    parallel \
    python-dev \
    python-pip \
    python-wheel \
    python-setuptools \
    unzip \
    vim \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

# install anaconda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -tipsy && \
    ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc

# prepend pytorch and conda-forge before default channel
RUN conda update conda && \
    conda config --prepend channels conda-forge && \
    conda config --prepend channels pytorch

# get dev version of solaris and create conda environment based on its env file
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN git clone https://github.com/cosmiq/solaris.git && \
    cd solaris && \
    git checkout ${solaris_branch} && \
    conda env create -f environment.yml
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/solaris/bin:$PATH

RUN cd solaris && pip install .

# install various conda dependencies into the space_base environment
RUN conda install -n solaris \
    jupyter \
    jupyterlab \
    ipykernel

# add a jupyter kernel for the conda environment in case it's wanted
RUN source activate solaris && python -m ipykernel.kernelspec \
    --name solaris --display-name solaris

# open ports for jupyterlab and tensorboard
EXPOSE 8888
EXPOSE 6006

RUN ["/bin/bash"]
```

After building the dockerfile into an image I attempt to expose the ports by running the following command:

```
docker run -p localhost:8888:8888 -p localhost:6006:6006 1ff
```

When I run `docker ps -a` I get the below image. As you can see the ports are not exposed. [image]

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04.

I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't `docker run` without `--detach` wait until the container has exited?

Comment: What's the last `RUN` command doing? Shouldn't this be a `ENTRYPOINT`? Btw your container has already exited, so maybe that's the reason... You didn't specify an entry point and you didn't use `-it` to interact with a shell inside the container. So the container exits immediately (?)

Comment: yes that's exactly it!! Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that... It's been a really long day :/